# Type Error on initialization of local serverless dynamodb

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I am getting Type Error on initialization in serverless-dynamodb-local/index.js:11:43.

How could I fix this issue?

```
directory  (my-git-branch) > serverless
  Serverless: Running "serverless" installed locally (in service node_modules)
  Serverless: To ensure safe major version upgrades ensure "frameworkVersion" setting in service configuration (recommended setup: "frameworkVersion: ^1.83.2")

  Serverless: Load command interactiveCli
  Serverless: Load command config
  Serverless: Load command config:credentials
  Serverless: Load command config:tabcompletion
  Serverless: Load command config:tabcompletion:install
  Serverless: Load command config:tabcompletion:uninstall
  Serverless: Load command create
  Serverless: Load command install
  Serverless: Load command package
  Serverless: Load command deploy
  Serverless: Load command deploy:function
  Serverless: Load command deploy:list
  Serverless: Load command deploy:list:functions
  Serverless: Load command invoke
  Serverless: Load command invoke:local
  Serverless: Load command info
  Serverless: Load command logs
  Serverless: Load command metrics
  Serverless: Load command print
  Serverless: Load command remove
  Serverless: Load command rollback
  Serverless: Load command rollback:function
  Serverless: Load command slstats
  Serverless: Load command plugin
  Serverless: Load command plugin
  Serverless: Load command plugin:install
  Serverless: Load command plugin
  Serverless: Load command plugin:uninstall
  Serverless: Load command plugin
  Serverless: Load command plugin:list
  Serverless: Load command plugin
  Serverless: Load command plugin:search
  Serverless: Load command config
  Serverless: Load command config:credentials
  Serverless: Load command rollback
  Serverless: Load command rollback:function
  Serverless: Load command upgrade
  Serverless: Load command uninstall

    Type Error ---------------------------------------------

    TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
        at new module.exports (/home/myFolder/node_modules/serverless-dynamodb-local/index.js:11:43)
        at PluginManager.addPlugin (/home/myFolder/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:94:28)
        at /home/myFolder/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:129:31
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at PluginManager.loadAllPlugins (/home/myFolder/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:129:8)
        at /home/myFolder/node_modules/serverless/lib/Serverless.js:88:39
        at tryCatcher (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
        at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
        at Promise._settlePromise (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
        at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
        at Promise._settlePromises (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)
        at Promise._fulfill (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:673:18)
        at Promise._settlePromise (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:617:21)
        at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
        at Promise._settlePromises (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)
        at Promise._fulfill (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:673:18)
        at Promise._resolveCallback (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:466:57)
        at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:559:17)
        at Promise._settlePromise (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
        at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
        at Promise._settlePromises (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)
        at Promise._fulfill (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:673:18)
        at PromiseArray._resolve (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise_array.js:127:19)
        at PromiseArray._promiseFulfilled (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise_array.js:145:14)
        at Promise._settlePromise (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:609:26)
        at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
        at Promise._settlePromises (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)
        at Promise._fulfill (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:673:18)
        at Promise._resolveCallback (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:466:57)
        at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:559:17)
        at Promise._settlePromise (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
        at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
        at Promise._settlePromises (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)
        at Promise._fulfill (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:673:18)
        at PropertiesPromiseArray.PromiseArray._resolve (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise_array.js:127:19)
        at PropertiesPromiseArray._promiseFulfilled (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/props.js:78:14)
        at Promise._settlePromise (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:609:26)
        at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
        at Promise._settlePromises (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)
        at _drainQueueStep (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)
        at _drainQueue (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
        at Async._drainQueues (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
        at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/myFolder/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
        at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:461:21)

    Get Support --------------------------------------------
       Docs:          docs.serverless.com
       Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
       Issues:        forum.serverless.com

    Your Environment Information ---------------------------
       Operating System:          linux
       Node Version:              12.20.1
       Framework Version:         2.18.0
       Plugin Version:            4.4.2
       SDK Version:               2.3.2
       Components Version:        3.4.7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in [this issue](https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline/issues/144#issuecomment-257596502), removing and re-installing serverless solved the problem for me:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g serverless
sudo npm i -g serverless
npm i -D serverless-offline
```